# Strange behavior with floated divs and sliding animation

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to achieve a multi-step form where each panel will slide out and slide in on button click.

I've managed to build the mechanism but I've hit a roadblock while testing it.

## Steps to reproduce:

1. Click *Next* to go to *Panel 2*
2. Click *Previous* to go back to *Panel 1*

In this case, *Panel 3* somehow comes into picture and sits below Panel 1. Why is this happening? Why doesn't it stay hidden?

However, if go all the way to *Panel 3* and then try to go back to *Panel 1*, everything works fine. It only breaks if I go back without visiting all the panels.

```js
var global = {};
global.main_width = $('#nl-multi-form').outerWidth();
global.nof = $('#fieldset fieldset').length;
global.fieldset_width = global.main_width;
$('#fieldset').css('width', global.nof * global.fieldset_width);
$('#fieldset fieldset').css('width', global.fieldset_width);

$('.nl-next').on('click', function(e){
 e.preventDefault();
 var $clicked_button = $(this);
 var $fieldset = $clicked_button.closest('fieldset');
 var $nextFieldset = $fieldset.next();
 var fieldset_width = $fieldset.outerWidth();
 $fieldset.animate({
  marginLeft:-fieldset_width+'px'
 }, 300);
 $nextFieldset.animate({    
  marginLeft:0+'px'
 }, 300);
 
});

$('.nl-previous').on('click', function(e){
 e.preventDefault();
 var $clicked_button = $(this);
 var $fieldset = $clicked_button.closest('fieldset');
 var $prevFieldset = $fieldset.prev(); 
 var fieldset_width = $fieldset.outerWidth();
 $fieldset.animate({
  marginLeft:fieldset_width+'px'
 }, 300);
 $prevFieldset.animate({
  marginLeft:0+'px'
 }, 300);
 
});
```

```css
#nl-multi-form{
 margin-top:10px;
 position:relative; 
 overflow:hidden;
}
.clear{
 clear:both;
}
#nl-multi-form fieldset{
 border:1px solid #ccc;
 min-height:100px;
 float:left; 
}
.nl-panel{ 
 padding:10px;
}
.nl-navigation{ 
 text-align:right; 
 padding-bottom:10px; 
}
.nl-navigation button{
 margin-left:10px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
 <div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
   <div id="nl-multi-form">
    <div id="fieldset">
     <fieldset>
      <div class="nl-panel">
       <h1>This is panel 1</h1>
       <div class="nl-navigation">
        <button class="btn btn-primary nl-next">Next</button>
       </div>
      </div>
     </fieldset>
     <fieldset>
      <div class="nl-panel">
       <h1>This is panel 2</h1>
       <div class="nl-navigation">
        <button class="btn btn-primary nl-previous">Previous</button><button class="btn btn-primary nl-next">Next</button>
       </div>
      </div>
     </fieldset>
     <fieldset>
      <div class="nl-panel">
       <h1>This is panel 3</h1>
       <div class="nl-navigation">
        <button class="btn btn-primary nl-previous">Previous</button><button class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
       </div>
      </div>
     </fieldset>     
     <div class="clear"></div>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: The best option would be to use SO's own code snippet system which works pretty much just like jsfiddle. No need for links to sites that might not be there anymore in x years. Plus all the code stays on SO that way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I found the solve of your issue. You must initialize `margin-left` for all panels except first.

```
$('#fieldset fieldset:not(:first-child)').css('margin-left', global.fieldset_width);
```

```js
var global = {};
global.main_width = $('#nl-multi-form').outerWidth();
global.nof = $('#fieldset fieldset').length;
global.fieldset_width = global.main_width;
$('#fieldset').css('width', global.nof * global.fieldset_width);
$('#fieldset fieldset:not(:first-child)').css('margin-left', global.fieldset_width);
$('#fieldset fieldset').css('width', global.fieldset_width);

$('.nl-next').on('click', function(e){
 e.preventDefault();
 var $clicked_button = $(this);
 var $fieldset = $clicked_button.closest('fieldset');
 var $nextFieldset = $fieldset.next();
 var fieldset_width = $fieldset.outerWidth();
 $fieldset.animate({
  marginLeft:-fieldset_width+'px'
 }, 300);
 $nextFieldset.animate({    
  marginLeft:0+'px'
 }, 300);
 
});

$('.nl-previous').on('click', function(e){
 e.preventDefault();
 var $clicked_button = $(this);
 var $fieldset = $clicked_button.closest('fieldset');
 var $prevFieldset = $fieldset.prev(); 
 var fieldset_width = $fieldset.outerWidth();
 $fieldset.animate({
  marginLeft:fieldset_width+'px'
 }, 300);
 $prevFieldset.animate({
  marginLeft:0+'px'
 }, 300);
 
});
```

```css
#nl-multi-form{
 margin-top:10px;
 position:relative; 
 overflow:hidden;
}
.clear{
 clear:both;
}
#nl-multi-form fieldset{
 border:1px solid #ccc;
 min-height:100px;
 float:left; 
}
.nl-panel{ 
 padding:10px;
}
.nl-navigation{ 
 text-align:right; 
 padding-bottom:10px; 
}
.nl-navigation button{
 margin-left:10px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
 <div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
   <div id="nl-multi-form">
    <div id="fieldset">
     <fieldset>
      <div class="nl-panel">
       <h1>This is panel 1</h1>
       <div class="nl-navigation">
        <button class="btn btn-primary nl-next">Next</button>
       </div>
      </div>
     </fieldset>
     <fieldset>
      <div class="nl-panel">
       <h1>This is panel 2</h1>
       <div class="nl-navigation">
        <button class="btn btn-primary nl-previous">Previous</button><button class="btn btn-primary nl-next">Next</button>
       </div>
      </div>
     </fieldset>
     <fieldset>
      <div class="nl-panel">
       <h1>This is panel 3</h1>
       <div class="nl-navigation">
        <button class="btn btn-primary nl-previous">Previous</button><button class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
       </div>
      </div>
     </fieldset>     
     <div class="clear"></div>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Doesn't seem to have solved it. Panel 3 still goes down below Panel 1

Comment: Sorry, now for sure fixed)

Comment: Yeh, I had figured out the error. It does seem to work now. However, can you explain why it is necessary to initialize `margin-left` on all the subsequent panels?

Comment: Make sure you timelines this solution! First, he uses jquery animate, which is a bad practices. Second, he animates `margin-left` which bombs browser rendering path. ^^^

Comment: @DenisIvanov So what would be the best way to go about achieving the same?

Comment: Yes, this is bad solution. But it's works. Your solution doesn't work because after you click on "next" button, and then "previous" your second fieldset has 720px width and 720px margin. That give a sum 720px(first fieldset)+720px(margin of second)+720px(second fieldset) = 2160px. And third fieldset just doesn't fit in parent element.

Comment: Use js animation api, try not to ask browser for layout properties, instead of margin-left use translateX (this will use GPU) and notify browser ahead of time with will-change property. And finally, use timeline extensively to make sure you are hitting 60fps.